# Understanding visual basic code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to Visual basic and followed a tutorial on how to filter a report viewer.

On the button click I call this function and pass the value within textbox1 as so:

```
Mysub(TextBox1.Text)
```

I have a rough understanding of what’s going on just by reading the code but I am wondering if any of you can annotate the code so I can have a full understanding of what’s happening (the tutorial I followed was not well documented)

Here is the Private sub:

```
Private Sub Mysub(ByVal make As String) 

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim adapter As New Database1DataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter 
    Dim table As New Database1DataSet.DataTable1DataTable 

    adapter.FillByModulename(table, make) 

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CType(table, DataTable)))
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() 


End Sub
```

FillByModulename is a query I created with the filter set to =@Modulename for the Module name column so whatever is entered into the textbox is what will be filtered in this column.

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Your rough understanding is probably correct.  Is there a specific line that confuses you?

Comment: Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CType(table, DataTable))), is the main reason why I posted this, the rest I have a pretty clear grasp of

Comment: My instinct is to close the question, but there's nothing explicitly against asking "what does my code do?". Still, what's the point of this post?

Comment: Your line is first creating a ReportDataSource with the name "DataSet1" - (this hooks into the report, the rdlc file) and with the value table ie the datatable we want to use to populate the report. Then it adds this ReportDataSource to the DataSources collection of the report we are working with; in other words, it binds the ReportDataSource, holding the data, to the report. Hope this helps :)